# Prove $(g+h)\circ f=g\circ f+ h\circ f$

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let $g,h,f$ be functions with domains and ranges on the real numbers.

I have to prove that $$(g+h)\circ f=g\circ f + h\circ f$$

It seems so simple, but I don't know where to start the proof. Maybe just show that for two step chains of multiplication, addition and exponentiation that this holds? I don't know how to do it in a very elegant way.

Comment: Hint: proving that $p=q$, where $p$ and $q$ are functions, means proving $p(x) = q(x)$ for every $x$.

Comment: Do you have formal definition for 1. a function 2. a composition function? Collecting all your definitions is typically a good place to start. Also, what do you think will suffice for showing two functions are the same function?

Comment: Simply follow definitions.  (g + h)(x) = g(x) + h(x) by definition and g(f)(x) = g(f(x)) so it follows (g + h)(f)(x) = (g + h)(f(x)) = g(f(x)) + h(f(x)).  That's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

- The definition of $(g+h)$ is that $(g+h)(x) = g(x)+h(x)$  for every real $x$.
- The definition of $f\circ g$ is that $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$ for every real $x$.

Also:

To prove that a function $F$ is equal to a function $G$, you need to show that if you take an arbitrary $x\in\mathbb R$, you have $F(x)=G(x)$. All you need to do is use the definitions.